# Summation on 1 <= i < j < k <= n in GLPK

Tags: ampl, glpk, mathprog

I have been trying to solve seriation problem by using GNU. But I couldn't write a summation like the following.

```
param n, integer, >= 3;
set O := 1..n;
param d{i in O,j in O};
var x{i in O,j in O}, binary, i < j;
var v{i in O,j in O,k in O}, binary, i < j < k;
maximize total: sum{i in O,j in O, i<j}(d[i,j] - d[j,i])* x[i,j] + sum{i in O,j in O, i<j}d[j,i];
s.t. tran{i in O,j in O,k in O, i<j<k}: x[i,j] + x[j,i] - x[i,k] + v[i,j,k] = 1;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use `:` instead of `,` in the "such that" clause `i < j`:

```
sum{i in O,j in O: i < j} ...
#                ^ note ':' here
```